# Can a SATA cable be too short?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance, sata, cable

In an attempt to clean up the wiring in my mini-tower desktop case and make it less of a mess to handle, I'm considering swapping out the longer SATA cables in it for ones that are only as short as they need to be. The market is full of [very short SATA cables](http://www.satacable.com/sata-cables/internal-angle-sata-cables.html):

[image: Screenshot of satacable.com]

However, the following [Seagate article](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/182453en) states:

> Serial ATA cables are available in many lengths up to 1 meter. Minimum cable length is 12 inches, using shorter cables can cause timing, or noise interference on the cable.

The above is the only source I've been able to find for the claim that SATA cables less than 12 inches will result in performance issues. Neither of the famous [Maximum PC](http://www.pcgamer.com/is-your-sata-cable-slowing-down-your-data-transfers-max-pc-investigates/) or [Puget Systems](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/SATA-3Gb-s-vs-6Gb-s-Cable-Performance-Revisited-183/) SATA cable benchmarks take cables less than 12 inches into account.

**For those who have had experience with these shorter cables - have you noticed any particular performance problems with them?**

**Even better, can anyone link to (or conduct) benchmarks that could shed some empirical light onto this claim?**

Comment: What does the SATA specification indicate with regards to the length of the data cable?

Comment: @Ramhound No idea.

Comment: The [SATA spec](http://www.lttconn.com/res/lttconn/pdres/201005/20100521170123066.pdf) makes no mention of cable length that I could find.

Comment: @DavidPostill How did you manage to find the spec? The closest I got was running up against [this](https://www.sata-io.org/purchase-spec), so I assumed it wasn't freely available.

Comment: @Hashim Google-fu :) I searched for "sata spec" and it was the 3rd link ...

Comment: I've used 8-inch cables for months with no detectable issues.

Comment: I've used <12 inch SATA cables, not certain of the precise length

Comment: I've worked with Dell and HP SFF systems that have 6" SATA cables, never encountering a problem attributable to the data cable. Such Tier 1 OEM systems undergo considerable reliability testing before being mass produced.

Comment: I didn't find this question before posting a similar question over at EE: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Cables,_connectors,_and_ports The answers there may be of interest from an electrical engineering perspective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Serial ATA Revision 3.0 Specification](http://www.lttconn.com/res/lttconn/pdres/201005/20100521170123066.pdf) makes no mention of *minimum* cable length that I could find, although **the shortest cable length referenced in the standard is 1 meter.**

The only reference I can find supporting the claim that shorter cables can cause timing or noise interference is from a paper entitled [Successful SAS/SATA Equipment Design and Development: What You Need to Know for 6 Gb/s and Beyond](https://www.anixter.com/content/dam/Suppliers/viavi/White%20Paper/Successful%20SATA%20Equipment%20Design.pdf):

> If a cable is too short, however, de-emphasis and equalization may actually end up overcompensating for a signal, actually reducing signal integrity.

However, further reading of the paper makes it clear that this only applies to SAS-2 cables, not SATA (note emphasis):

> **Don’t use too short a cable for SAS-2:**
>
> While this may  seem to contradict the previous point, SAS-2 employs
> de-emphasis and equalization to attempt to overcome the effects of
> attenuation and jitter. However, as endpoints don’t communicate as to
> how much de-emphasis and equalization there should be, these values
> are fixed within a range  with expectation that they will work over
> the specification’s supported cable lengths.
>
> If a cable is too short, however, de-emphasis and equalization may actually end up  overcompensating for a signal, actually reducing
> signal integrity.
>
> While the specification supposedly can work  for any range of cable
> length, if you encounter issues with  short cables working with SAS-2,
> try experimenting with  longer lengths to determine if this is the
> problem. **Note that short cable issues do not apply to SATA as SATA
> does not support de-emphasis or equalization.**

Further, it seems that for SATA the shorter the cable the better:

> Other ways developers can improve signal integrity include:
>
> ...
>
> **Use the shortest reasonable cable:**
>
> The longer the cable,  the greater the attenuation. The best way to
> reduce attenuation is by shortening cables. This is especially true
> for  SATA, where the absence of the SAS specification’s de-emphasis
> and equalization mean that the link’s characteristics completely
> control signal attenuation and jitter.

---

#### In conclusion: despite cables shorter than 1 metre not being part of the SATA specification, the shortness of a SATA cable does *not* inhibit its performance, and may even improve it.

---

#### Further Reading

- [Successful SAS/SATA Equipment Design and Development](https://www.anixter.com/content/dam/Suppliers/viavi/White%20Paper/Successful%20SATA%20Equipment%20Design.pdf)
- [Serial ATA Revision 3.0 Specification](http://www.lttconn.com/res/lttconn/pdres/201005/20100521170123066.pdf)

Comment: “The shortest cable length referenced in the standard is 1 meter.“ - This would indicate this is the shortest officially supported.  It also could be the reason other sources are making similar assumptions

Comment: So essentially, the conclusion is that there's no such thing as too short a cable when it comes to SATA? I'd recommend emboldening the last sentence of the last quote, as that seems to be the most pertinent to answering this question. Other than that, great answer, thanks.

Comment: @Hashim The standard makes no mention of the length of the cable which means there isn’t anything stopping anyone from creating a cable that doesn’t have issues due to its length (most of the presumed issues are easily solved with good product engineering) likewise by only mentioning 1 meter or greater length the shortest cable most manufacturers will make will be that length (for a variety of reasons)

Comment: Doesn't the opening assertion that short cables are a problem [presumably for SATA cables as per the Question] contradict the end of the final quote: *"Note that short cable issues do not apply to SATA as SATA does not support de-emphasis or equalization..."*?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Yes, but many SATA drives are connected to SAS backplanes or controllers ...

Comment: @DavidPostill OK, if the answer's assertion applies to some drives and not others, it seems like that should be explained more clearly. There are plenty of SATA drives connected to pure SATA controllers (arguably including the OP's system).